# Total number of particles in the universe (according to Planck Surveyor measures, 2018)

Tags: cosmology, universe, baryons

Recently, [Marco Ajello et al. (2018)](https://cosmosmagazine.com/science/physics/how-many-photons-in-the-universe-go-on-have-a-guess/) has estimated the total number of photons in the whole observable universe as:

$$N_\gamma \approx 4\cdot 10^{84}$$

on the other hand, the [ratio of baryons to photons](https://ned.ipac.caltech.edu/level5/Sept02/Roos/Roos4.html) or the baryon abundance is defined as:

$$\eta \equiv \frac{N_b}{N_\gamma} \simeq 2.75 \times 10^{-8} \; \Omega{_b}h^2$$

being $\Omega{_b}h^2 = 0.0224 \pm 0.0001$ according to the [Planck surveyor measures](https://arxiv.org/abs/1807.06209) of 2018. All these numbers, suggest (if I am not confusing the data) that the total number of baryons in the universe is about:

$$N_b \approx 2.5\cdot 10^{75}$$

My question if this number is in agreement with other experimental measures of baryonic abundance (I have not been able to find a suitable reference), already taking into account the [missing baryon problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Missing_baryon_problem)